# div doesn't resize with twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

With Bootstrap loaded, the div doesn't expand along with the contents inside. So if I insert an image or enlarge the text, it just kind of...gets squished in or squished out of the div.

http://jsfiddle.net/thomaswtsang/SSmJt/3/

What is it about Bootstrap that causes this to do this?

Comment: Can you show us what you expect should happen? Would you like the div to get larger as the line of text cannot fit inside anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the bootsrap css used by you does not have the responsive features.

Please download the [bootstrap library](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) from the [customize option](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html).

You can have a look at this modified [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SSmJt/41/). You need to add some structural changes also as defined by bootstrap. You need to place the `spanx` definitions inside a `row` element to work correctly.

Comment: thanks for the extra info, wasn't aware of customization options.